# What is the service layer in an ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm having problems to understand the conception of DDD. I have an ASP.NET project with this structure:

ASP.NET MVC4 project: xxx.UI.Web

Class Library project: xxx.Application xxx.Domain xxx.Infra.EF

I'm trying to keep this relation:

> xxx.UI.Web only have relation with xxx.Domain and xxx.Application
>
> xxx.Domain doesn't have relations.
>
> xxx.Application have relation with xxx.Domain and xxx.Infra.EF
>
> xxx.Infra.EF have relation with xxx.Domain

But now I'm having many problems to keep this concepts with Entity Framework. I have created the Entity repositories in the xxx.Infra.EF and created a generic repository (with interfaces and so on) in xxx.Application.

The problems begin when I need to pass a personalized Entity context to my repositories, because I use the repositories in the xxx.UI.Web and I can't instantiate a new Entity context because It will broke my project pattern (The Entity context comes from xxx.Infra.EF).

My idea is to create many helper methods that will process this kind of operations for my xxx.UI.Web, and I wouldn't like to create this methods in xxx.Application (It looks a little strange to create many methods with a little relation with my business logic).

So I was reading a little about Domain Driven Development (DDD) and I knew about the Service layer, and I think It seems to be the layer that was created to solve problems like this, or not?

My idea is to create a new class library project called xxx.Service and make this project keep relation with xxx.Domain and xxx.Infra.EF. Is It right? I know that I could search for another solutions for my case with Entity context, but I guess I'll have more problems like this in the future with other things, so I tried to find solutions for It. I should study much more about It, but I think I could identify the solution for my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a personalized Entity context" ? What are you trying to do ? Btw there's no "Service *layer*" per se in DDD...

Comment: I need to have a better control of the lifetime of the context, because sometimes I need to use the same context in many repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you further study the concept of layered architecture.

You are correct that the Domain should not reference other layers, such as the Presentation Layer and Infrastructure Layer.

The most common style of layered architecture is the "Onion Architecture". See image and link below.

[image]

http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/

**The Service Layer**

You are also correct that a new layer (Service Layer) will solve your problem. You see, the problem arises because the UI/Presentation Layer is talking directly to the repositories(Infrastructure).

In our approach, the Presentation Layer does not communicate directly with the Infrastructure and Domain. We have a Service layer that comes between the Presentation and the Domain.

[image]

The above architecture borrows heavily from the Onion Architecture. We don't have domain services. Application Core is our CrossCutting Layer.

Answer (score 3):

People often misunderstand the point of a multi-tiered application. The goal is not necessarily to remove dependencies, but rather to encapsulate and modularize code. Your MVC frontend shouldn't need to be concerned with your entities and how their queried, added, updated, etc., but it doesn't mean it doesn't need access to them. Long and short, don't focus on project references, but rather factoring out code that is not in each project's "domain" into a more appropriate "domain".

To that end, it's not really possible to say based on the information you provided exactly what you should do. The question is opinionated to begin with and will very likely end up being closed as a result. Ultimately, you have to decide what's best for your project. Do what makes sense, rather than blindly following some pattern. After all, patterns are supposed to just be a codification of common sense approaches to common problems, anyways.